# Filter twitter4j stream

Tags: java, filter, twitter4j

I'm trying to filter my twitter4j stream with the following code :

```
    TwitterStream twitterStream = getTwitterStreamInstance();

    // Listener
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);

    // Filter
    FilterQuery filtre = new FilterQuery();
    String[] keywordsArray = { "iphone", "samsung" };
    filtre.track(keywordsArray);
    twitterStream.filter(filtre);

    // Listening
    twitterStream.sample();
```

But the result is, for example :

```
27/59 - "Taking a risk over something only means that you want it more than anything"
28/63 - The more attractive you are, the more awkward I am.
29/64 - the thing about pain is that it demands to be felt
```

And I don't recover the keywords I want to follow, where is the problem ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need:

```
twitterStream.sample();
```

If you remove it, you should start seeing Tweets matching your filter query.

When you invoke `filter` your listener will receive filtered Tweets, however because you then invoke `sample` you are effectively replacing the filtered-stream your listener is receiving with the sample steam, which is a random selection Tweets.

So in other words call either [`sample`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html#sample%28%29) or [`filter`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html#filter%28twitter4j.FilterQuery%29), but not both.

Comment: Great ! It was my problem. I also have another small question. If I choose to track a keyword that is not used much. Am I sure to reap all the tweets about?

Comment: @Apaachee I can't say this with completely certainty but I would expect so. I skimmed the docs and didn't notice anything significant - with the exception of [withheld content](http://dev.twitter.com/blog/new-withheld-content-fields-api-responses).

Comment: @Apaachee No problem - I'm glad I could help. :-) I'm not sure if you know, but you can [mark an answer as 'accepted'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/195234) if you feel it answers your question.

Comment: @Apaachee It is possible that you might miss out on the unindexed tweets. Twitter does not take any guarantee of providing you with all of them.

Comment: @vishalv2050 Yes, but if the frequency of the tweets is enough low, you got them. So, with a big tweets filter, you can have all the tweets.